# How to setup a tagging system with sqlite and php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a PHP frontend with an image gallery. The data/metadata for the images is pulled from a sqlite database table.

Now I'd like the user to be able to tag the images, e.g. giving image1 the tags "boat" & "fish", and giving image2 some other or the same tags. How would I set up the database for this?

My idea is to create a new table where each row is a tag with an ID.

But how do I add these IDs into the image details table to connect both tables? Afaik I can't simply add a new column to the image table that contains the tag ids as an array, since sqlite doesn't support that.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would have to create a new table for tags.

In your case, best thing would be to create an intermediate table, (let's call it **image_tag**) which has an **image_id** and a **tag_id** column. Now if you want to let's say assign two tags to an image, you can just insert 2 records in the image_tag table containing that image's id and the ids of the tags.

This is called a **many to many** relationship as one image could have more than one tag and more than one image could have one tag.

Maybe this could give you a rough idea:

**Image Table**

```
id path
1  image.jpg
```

**Tags Table**

```
id name
1  fish
2  boat
```

**image_tag Table**

```
id image_id tag_id
1  1        1
1  1        2
```

For more info, please refer to [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/sqlite-create-table-foreign-key-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use child table then you can add tag in same row same table using serialize fields.

Like,

```
$returnValue = serialize(array('fish','boat'));

ID IMAGE      TAG
1  Image.jpg  a:2:{i:0;s:4:"fish";i:1;s:4:"boat";}
```

And you can simply read this `$returnValue = unserialize($row['TAG']);`